# Angular 2 configure routes dynamically

Tags: angular, routes

I am new to Angular 2. We are building an application, where the menu needs to be rendered dynamically based on the user's role. For some roles, certain menu items should be hidden.

The user's details (name, role) need to be fetched upon startup (bootstrap) from a web service.

This presents a problem. The routes need to be specified in the AppModule, whereas the fetching of user's details would be done inside the AppComponent, post which the routes can be decided. How can we setup the routes dynamically post the web service call?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I`d just use `*ngIf="..."` to show/hide the menu instead of dynamic routes or `*ngFor` to generate menu entries from an array.

Comment: I agree with @GünterZöchbauer you could also use a [Route Guard](https://angular.io/guide/router#milestone-5-route-guards) to prevent user access to certain routes until they have logged in.

Comment: Route Guards would get called always whether the user is accessing the route using the Menu or directly via the browser address bar. Is there a way to distinguish, so that in case of legitimate access via the Menu, we can skip some of the checks, whereas illegitimate access gets blocked?